# How do you "translate" this into <script setup>?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

How would you do this, but with using script setup?

```
<script>
export default {
name: "App",
methods: {
scrollToElement() {
  const [el] = this.$refs.section;
  if (el) {
    el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
},
 },
};
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Line by line. SO is q&a, not code-writing service. The question is more likely to be answered if it shows some research and addresses specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<template>
  <button @click="scrollToElement()">
    Scroll to el
  </button>
  ...
  <div ref="section">
    <p>something</p>
  </div>
  ...
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";

  const section = ref();

  const scrollToElement = () => {
    section.value.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).